# How to load multiple modules implementing the same behaviour

Tags: import, module, erlang

I do not understand how is one supposed to use multiple modules that each implement the same behaviour since i get this error at compile time:

> Function is already imported from

In my case i have two modules implementing `gen_event` behaviour and i am trying to import them in a third module.
I get the error message whenever i am trying to compile this code:

```
-module(mgr).
-import(h1,[init/1]).   // implements gen_event
-import(h2,[init/1]).   // implements gen_event
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Import is a simple trick to avoid to write the complete "definition" of a function. It does nothing but just says to the compiler : when you see `init(P)` in this module, replace with `h1:init(P)`.

Thus it is not possible to import several function with the same name/arity.

For short names, I do not see any benefit to use import.

If you are using module:function with long names, and you want to shorten the lines in the code, it is possible to use macros instead, and there are no limitation (but also few chance that the function name are the same :o):

```
-define(Func1(Var1,...,VarN), module1:func(Var1,...,VarN)). 
-define(Func2(Var1,...,VarN), module2:func(Var1,...,VarN)). 
...
?Func1(A1,...,AN);
...
?Func2(B1,...,BN);
```

**Edit**

The next example illustrates how it works, first I create the module mod1 as follow:

```
-module (mod1).

-export ([test/1]).

test(P) ->
    case P of 
        1 -> ok;
        2 -> mod2:test()
    end.
```

and I test it in the shell:

```
1> c(mod1).
{ok,mod1}
2> mod1:test(1).
ok
3> mod1:test(2).
** exception error: undefined function mod2:test/0
4> % this call failed because mod2 was not defined.
4> % lets define it and compile.
```

mod2 is created as:

```
-module (mod2).

-export ([test/0]).

test() ->
    io:format("now it works~n").
```

continue in the shell:

```
4> c(mod2).
{ok,mod2}
5> mod1:test(1).                                   
ok
6> mod1:test(2).                                   
now it works
ok
7>
```

As you can see, it is not necessary to modify `mod1`, but only to create and compile `mod2` (note that it would be the same if mod2 already exists but the function test/0 is not exported).

If you want to verify that your code is not using undefined function, you can use external tools. As I am using [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/getting-started) to manage my projects, I use the command rebar3 xref to perform this check. Note that calling an undefined function is a simple warning, it is meaningful in the context of application upgrading. This verification is not bullet proof: it is done at build time, this does not guarantee that the modules yo need will be present, with the right version on a production system: it opens a lot more interesting questions about versioning, code loading...

Comment: Also, the local function wrapping the call to the remote; if this is used frequently, [`Kernel.defdelegate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defdelegate/2) might be backported from [tag:elixir].

Comment: Well i thought that when you `import` you also get the `imported` module compiled and so you shoot 2 birds with one stone (language terseness + compilation). So if my module `Parent` uses another module `Child` i do not need to import it , i can just call `Child:method()` ( if  i compile the `Child` beforehand) ?

Comment: There is no order in compilation. The call is solved at runtime: if the called module is not loaded in the VM, it will load it first, then it will look for the function. If it exists, fine, it will execute the call; if it doesn't exist, then it will simply fail during execution.

Comment: But the problem in my case is that i am not the one using `init`.Init in my case is used by the `gen_event:add_handler` method.It is library code that expects an `init` in the target module.In my case i have multiple modules that implement the `gen_event` behaviour, and they all need to expose `init`.

Comment: So you have no choice but calling each of them using `h1:init(), h2:init(),..` . Nevertheless, in the case of behaviors, the init functions are callback functions which are automatically called by the behavior module when you start a process. you don't need to invoke them explicitly.

Comment: No that is what i am saying , i do not need to call them explicitly, and i am not .But if i try to load `2` modules implementing the same behaviour, i get the `function [function name] is already defined` error.It does not let me load the second module that exposes the same behaviour (even if i am not calling it and its just a handler).

Comment: OK, I have done this in a former project, I'll try to retrieve this example and propose a simplified version.